# How to use `$order->get_discount_total()`, avoiding defoult WC decimal rounding?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, order

I am trying to build a custom functionality for my WP website, where I need to get the full amount of discounts aplied in given order. So far I am able to get the amount, rounded to a whole number (for example '10'), but I need the value with the decimals and I know the real value is '10.50'

I have read about WC defoult decimal rounding and in fact, when I change it in woocommerce->settings to 2 (defoults to 0) my code works great. But I am not able to use this solution because my co-workers told me that changing this defoult value may result in unexpected behavior of our custom checkout.

So the question is how to avoid the defoult WC decimal rounding settings and get order_discount_total with the decimal integers?

`$order->get_discount_total()` ---> outputs to '10' / expected '10.50'

Comment: maybe `wc_format_decimal($order->get_total_discount(), 2)` ?